# How would I create a tab indicator in NavigationDrawer?

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

How do I create a navigation draw tab indicator like this? Does the `NavigationDrawer` class have an indicator like `TabLayout`?

[image]

Comment: Use custom views for drawer items instead of menu , I am not sure if the above customization is possible with menu . simple indication can be shown by using `<group android:checkableBehavior="single">`  in menu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define a custom drawable with a left border and set it as the background of the selected item. Follow the steps given below,

> Step 1: Define a drawable with left border(selected_item.xml) in drawables

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item>
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <solid android:color="#000000" />
    </shape>
</item>
<item android:left="2dp">
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <solid android:color="#FF0000" />
    </shape>
</item>
</layer-list>
```

> Step 2: Define a selector(navi_selector.xml) in drawables

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:state_checked="true" android:drawable="@drawable/selected_item"/>
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="#000000"/>

</selector>
```

> Step 3: set the navi_selector for app:itemBackground

```xml
 <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        app:itemTextColor="@android:color/white"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer"
        android:background="#000000"
        app:itemBackground="@drawable/navi_selector"/>
```

Comment: Wonderful! Thanks!